# Trie longest prefix matching

Tags: java, trie

I didn't get the end of the word concept in trie. I think my understanding of trie itself is incomplete. Can someone please explain the following piece in the code [HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-prefix-matching-a-trie-based-solution-in-java/)

```
// If this is end of a word, then update prevMatch
               if( crawl.isEnd() ) 
                    prevMatch = level + 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the code is climbing the trie searching for the longest prefix for a gifen word.

Say you have a trie that already contains the words:

"of"
"one"
"once"

and you are trying to search for the longest prefix of "onerous", which you would expect to come out at 3 (i.e. "one" is the longest prefix already present.

The code being executed reads:

```
    // See if there is a Trie edge for the current character
    if (child.containsKey(ch)) {
        result += ch;          //Update result
        crawl = child.get(ch); //Update crawl to move down in Trie

        // If this is end of a word, then update prevMatch
        if (crawl.isEnd()) {
            prevMatch = level + 1;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
```

so imagine you are looking at the "n" of "onerous". You discover that "on" is in the trie as a fragment but is not an `end` (because you have not put the word "on" in the trie but the word "one" **is** in there). This code will continue climbing the tree with the next character "e" but will not change `prevMatch`. When it looks at the "e" however, there is a match in the tree **and** it is an `end` because the word "one" is in the tree so this code stores `3` in `prevMatch`.

Answer (score 1):

The IsEnd killswitch is set when the word ends but it's not the end of the trie or the search. The words  are stored lexicographical into a tree or hashmap. It can happen the search word is not the first or second killswitch.